# Estimating a GARCH-M model with a mean-equation dummy

Tags: self-study, garch

I'm trying to estimate a GARCH-M model with a dummy volatility variable on the mean equation, so the mean equation looks something like this:

$$r_t = \mu  + \lambda_1{\mkern 1mu} \sigma_t + \lambda_2 D_1\sigma_2$$

$$\sigma _t^2 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1\varepsilon_{t - 1}^2 + \beta_1\sigma_{t - 1}^2$$

In other words, maybe this is more clear: what I'm trying to see is if the risk premia increased on the dates where the dummy variable took a value of 1 ($\lambda_2$) versus all the other days ($\lambda_1$).

However, I'm not sure how I can estimate such equation (preferably on Eviews) or even if such equation is feasible/makes sense.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\sigma_2$? Generally, I do not see any problem with your model. You should be able to estimate it with standard software that has GARCH-in-mean model with the option of including additional variables to the mean equation.